# For mapping the contents of a directory, is there a difference between the CFURLEnumerator and the NSDirectoryEnumerator?

Tags: macos, cocoa, directory, traversal, core-foundation

I am working on a project where I need to recursively iterate through the sub-directories of a given folder, and essentially grab the paths of all of the children in that folder. Both the CFURLEnumerator and the NSDirectoryEnumerator do that, but I can't decide which one to use. Is there a speed difference between the two?

I'd appreciate to hear if anyone has had experience with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think any difference in speed would be swamped by the fact that you have to read the directory structure off the disk.  I'd always go with the NS- version because Cocoa is a bit easier to work with than Core Foundation.

Comment: Do you think using `NSTask` and calling `find` would be better?

Comment: @newenglander No.  That has the additional overhead of creating a whole new process.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDirectoryEnumerator` uses `CFURLEnumerator` so you'll see very little difference in performance.

`CFURLEnumerator` provides a couple of enumerator options - `kCFURLEnumeratorIncludeDirectoriesPreOrder` and `kCFURLEnumeratorIncludeDirectoriesPostOrder` - that are not exposed by Cocoa API. Those options are useful if you need to control when directories are returned during recursive enumerations. For example, if you want to use `CFURLEnumerator` to enumerate and delete the contents of a directory hierarchy, you'll need to delete directories *after* you delete the directories' descendants. The `kCFURLEnumeratorIncludeDirectoriesPostOrder` option let you see the directory URL after you've seen all of its descendents.

Comment: A NSDirectoryEnumerationIncludesDirectoriesPostOrder option and a isEnumeratingDirectoryPostOrder property were added in macOS 10.15/iOS 13.0. That means NSDirectoryEnumerator now does everything CFURLEnumerator does.